# ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (9,) but got array with shape (1,)

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning, valueerror

hi so I build a DNN network to classify some objects in an image using the features of the object, like bellow :

```
contours, _ = cv2.findContours(imgthresh, cv2.RETR_TREE, cv2.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE)

for contour in contours:
    features = np.array([])
    (x_start, y_start, character_width, character_height) = cv2.boundingRect(contour)
    x_end = x_start + character_width
    y_end = y_start + character_height
    character_area = character_width * character_height
    features = np.append(features, [character_width, character_height, character_area, x_start,
                                    y_start, x_end, y_end, image_width, image_height])

    print(features)
    print(features.shape)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (x_start, y_start), (x_end, y_end), (0, 255, 0), thickness=1)
```

`print(features)` output is:

```
[  5.   1.   5. 105.  99. 110. 100. 100. 117.]
```

and `print(features.shape)` is:

```
(9,)
```

I build and trained a DNN using the following code :

```
model = Sequential()

model.add(Dense(50, input_dim=9, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(40, activation='relu'))

model.add(Dropout(0.5))

model.add(Dense(30,activation='relu'))

model.add(Dense(2, activation='softmax'))
```

The input layer has 9 input features. So I tried to get the prediction of the model using:

```
model.predict_classes(features)
```

The  training data, a `CSV`  file,  contains 10 columns (9 features and 1 for the output)

I got the following error :

```
ValueError: Error when checking input: expected dense_1_input to have shape (9,) but got array with shape (1,)
```

I tried to reshape the features array by using :

```
np.reshape(features,(1,9)
```

but that didn't work either. I am still new at this field

Comment: What does the `print(features)` line outputs? As you initialize your array with `np.array([])` and then append something, I suppose that the first element of your array is an list of shape (1,)

Comment: @AlexisBRENON  sorry forgot to put the output of it in the question I will update it now

Comment: @AlexisBRENON I updated the question with the output values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal working example.

```py
import numpy as np
import tensorflow as tf

def main():
    features = np.array([5, 1, 5, 105, 99, 110, 100, 100, 117])
    model = tf.keras.Sequential()
    model.add(tf.keras.layers.Dense(50, input_dim=9, activation="relu"))

    print(tf.expand_dims(features, 0))
    print(np.reshape(features, (1, 9)))

    print(model.predict_classes(np.reshape(features, (1, 9))))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

As you can see, the `np.reshape` call make it works. It is roughly equivalent to the `tf.expand_dims`.

Your current error comes from the fact that your model expect a batch dimension.
So, if you pass it an array of shape `(9,)` it infers that it's a batch of scalars, and not a single array of size 9.